# How to install TensorFlow 2.x with Eigen AVX512 support?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, tensorflow2.0, avx512

Is there a pip package available for Tensorflow-Eighen with AVX512 support?

I've installed Tensorflow using the following two commands.

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

in both cases, I get the following warning.

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
```

[This](https://technofob.com/2019/06/14/how-to-compile-tensorflow-2-0-with-avx2-fma-instructions-on-mac/) helps but I don't want to clone and build and I also don't want to install tensorflow-mkl. I want to use Eigen with AVX512 support.

Update:
ref: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39890)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to build it yourself. Beware though, building the tensorflow source from scratch takes hours on a high-end desktop.

Comment: yeah. That's what I heard.